# How can I change the CIFAR-10 dataset labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I want to change some labels of dataset CIFAR-10.
That mean, I want to train my networks with some wrongs labels in this dataset.

After change the dataset labels, I need it in some format like:

```
dataset_cifar_with_some_wrongs_labels = (amount of pictures, label, image)

image.shape=(32,32,3)
```

I know I can download it as:

[https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html)

Someone know how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *keras* internal *cifar10* dataset. I have implemented a noise mechanism via permutation but there are probably many other choices.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
n = 1000
y_train_ = y_train.copy()
idx_to_shuffle = np.random.choice(y_train.shape[0], n)
y_train[idx_to_shuffle] = np.random.permutation(y_train[idx_to_shuffle])
```